# Xcode:How to import parent's header in a sub-project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, import

I've a project that has a subproject (an XPC worker). Here I need to import one header from the main(parent) project. How do I do this?

[image]

I tried by setting(Sub project's) Header Search Path, User Header Search Path with values like `$(SRCROOT)` & `$(SRCROOT)/../Interface.h`. Also tried by changing the settings Recursive and Non-Recursive.

Comment: Set the *Header Search Path* for that target.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I just updated the question, with whatever I tried...

Comment: You are using backslashes (`\\`)?

Comment: @trojanfoe: As I dragged the file, it(Sorry "/" forward slashes) came. I also tried only with `$(SRCROOT)`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve these issues is to look at the actual compiler line when building the target to see what folders are being specified in the `-I` options and work from there.  You need to go to the *Build Log*, find a file being compiled and then expand the command using the dropdown button thing on the right of the line.

The structure for all projects is fairly unique, so it's almost impossible to provide a *one-size-fits-all* fix for this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally I did it but still not sure that is the correct way or not. In the Sub-Projects' Build Phase I added the Interface.h file. Now the subproject is able to find it. Yours view on this, please.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya There should be no need to move or copy the file.  You can set any directory relative to `$(SRCROOT)`; for example `$(SRCROOT)/ProjectName/SubProjectName`, or whatever.

Comment: Or may be Due to the Target Dependency, it happend?

Comment: No, as the header files are not copied during the build.  It's all about looking at what is being set during the build and adjusting *Header Search Path* accordingly.